# How to make Python absolute import lines shorter?

Tags: python, testing, pytest

this is my project structure (just an example to illustrate the problem):

```
.
├── hello_world
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── some
│       └── very_nested
│           └── stuff.py
└── tests
    └── test_stuff.py
```

The `test_stuff.py` file (for `py.test`):

```
from hello_world.some.very_nested.stuff import Magic
from hello_world.some.very_nested.other_stuff import MoreMagic

def test_magic_fact_works():
    assert Magic().fact(3) == 6

# ...
```

**Is there any way how to make the import lines shorter?** They get too long in the real project.

For example, this would be nice, but it doesn't work :)

```
import hello_world.some.very_nested as vn
from vn.stuff import Magic
from vn.other_stuff import MoreMagic
```

I cannot use relative imports (I assume) beucase the tests are not inside the package. I could move them, but is it possible without changing project structure?

Comment: Why don't you use `__init__.py` files to aggregate useful names up the package stack?

Comment: Can't say this ever bothered me.  Use PyCharm, where they are folded away.

Comment: Instead of `from vn.stuff import Magic` you could do instead `Magic = vn.stuff.Magic` for the same effect

Comment: @wim: That assumes the `stuff` submodule is already loaded, though.

Comment: That looks good - importing submodules is much better than polluting namespace with names that are useful just for a few tests.

Answer (score 0):

As @jonrsharpe says, you can aggregate your packages in a django style:

```
"""
Django validation and HTML form handling.
"""

from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError  # NOQA
from django.forms.boundfield import *  # NOQA
from django.forms.fields import *  # NOQA
from django.forms.forms import *  # NOQA
from django.forms.formsets import *  # NOQA
from django.forms.models import *  # NOQA
from django.forms.widgets import *  # NOQA
```

And in your subpackage, eg.: `django.forms.widgets` add this:

```
__all__ = (
    'Media', 'MediaDefiningClass', 'Widget', 'TextInput', 'NumberInput',
    'EmailInput', 'URLInput', 'PasswordInput', 'HiddenInput',
    'MultipleHiddenInput', 'FileInput', 'ClearableFileInput', 'Textarea',
    'DateInput', 'DateTimeInput', 'TimeInput', 'CheckboxInput', 'Select',
    'NullBooleanSelect', 'SelectMultiple', 'RadioSelect',
    'CheckboxSelectMultiple', 'MultiWidget', 'SplitDateTimeWidget',
    'SplitHiddenDateTimeWidget', 'SelectDateWidget',
)
```

To specify which items you want to import when using `import *`, this way you can organize your packages as deep as you want and keep them accessible at the same time.

In your case it would be something like:

**hello_world/__init__.py**

```
from hello_world.some.very_nested.stuff import *
from hello_world.some.very_nested.other_stuff import *
```

SO when importing your packages in tests for instance, you get this: `from hello_world import Magic`

Answer (score 0):

Put into `hello_world/__init__.py`:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from .some import *
```

Into `hello_world/some/__init__.py`:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from .very_nested import *
```

Into `hello_world/some/very_nested/__init__.py`:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from .stuff import Magic
from .other_stuff import MoreMagic
```

So if `hello_world/some/very_nested/stuff.py` contains:

```
class Magic:
    pass
```

And `hello_world/some/very_nested/other_stuff.py` contains:

```
class OtherMagic:
    pass
```

Then you can easy import it. `tests/test_stuff.py`:

```
import pytest
from hello_world import Magic
from hello_world import MoreMagic

@pytest.mark.parametrize('cls', [Magic, MoreMagic])
def test_magic(cls):
    assert cls()
```